# Write $1/z$ as a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the function $f(z)=1/z$ can be represented as a power series in a ball $B(z_0,r)$, where $z_0 \neq 0$. Find the radius of convergence of this power series.

$$f(z)=\frac1z = \frac1{z_0+z-z_0}= \frac1{z_0(1+(z-z_0)/z_0)}$$

Then what do I do?

Comment: Use $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z_0\left(1+\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_0}\right)}=\dfrac{1}{z_0}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_0}}=\dfrac{1}{z_0}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_0}\right)^k$$
$$\therefore f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z_0}\left[1-\left(\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_0}\right)+\left(\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_0}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_0}\right)^3+\ldots\right]$$